# IE8 Block elements with width/height not detecting a mouseover until text inside is hovered

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In IE8 block elements with a set width/height will display properly but mouse events and linking only work for text inside of that element. A mouseover will not be detected until the text inside of the element is hovered. If it's a link only the text will be clickable. If I remove the doctype (sending it into quirks mode) it works fine but breaks a lot of the styling on the site. Is there any way I can get this to work properly?

Comment: Note that if you want to send IE into an older mode you can use [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which may be better than just removing the doctype. For an answer to your question: I gave sdo's suggestion +1

Comment: It looks like you posted a solution within your question.  If you've indeed found the solution, it's best for future readers if you post it as an answer below and then "accept" your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the presence of a noscript tag in the page. Removing it fixed the issue. I have no idea why that would be the case but perhaps someone else can elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of issues with the traditional mouse events. I highly recommend using JQuery's mouseenter() and mouseleave() events. They travel through the dom to make sure the mouse is definitely in or out of the object in question. There is even a shorthand for binding events; you can use the convenience method hover() to bind both events to an element at once like this:

```
$( "#some-element" ).hover(
  function(){
   // mouse is inside the element
  },
  function(){
   // mouse is outside the element
  }
);
```

[Check it out](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's been quite awhile but I believe I originally used hover and attempted other methods in looking for a solution. Regardless, none of these or the native methods worked but the problem instead appeared to be caused by the presence of a noscript tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently where the `mouseenter` event was working only if you were on top of a link inside the block element.  (My issue was with IE 7 however.)

Try adding `zoom: 1` to the block element.

```
#myBlockElement {
    zoom: 1;
}
```

http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html

---

I also agree with the other answer about [using `.hover()` in place of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), but that alone will probably not solve your problem with IE.

---

I also like to make sure I have a valid `DOCTYPE` and that my page is fully [compliant in the W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) before working on any IE issues.